# Clustered Index on NON-Primary Key Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Creating Clustered Index on a NON-Primary Key Column, Will sort the values and store ONLY on Disk[ if VARCHAR then A-Z] and Not necessary to show them on query result set ?

Though the record inserted is not in order why query output always sorted based on primary key column [ not clustered]?

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( N INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(10))
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_1 ON TEST(NAME)
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD  PRIMARY KEY (N)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2,'D'),(1,'C'),(4,'A'),(3,'B'),(100,'Z')
SELECT * FROM TEST
output:
N  NAME
1   C
2   D
3   B
4   A
100 Z
```

I thought result set would return like this :

```
N  NAME
4   A
3   B
1   C
2   D
100 Z
```

Comment: For an interesting look at unexpected sorting, read [Hugo's blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx) article.

Comment: Good one! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Rows in a relational database are not sorted. The **only** (really: the *only*) way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by`.  You didn't use an `order by` so the database is free to return the rows in _any_ order it likes. If you need a specific sort order you **have** to use `order by`. There is no alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two assumptions

1. `Select` query will result in the *logical* order `clustered Index` in your case it is `NAME` column

It is wrong. Unless you mention `Order By` in your `select` query result order is not *guaranteed*. Though you are seeing the result sorted in Primary key column(Non clustered Index) but the order is not guaranteed

2. Records of `Clustered Index` column is stored in `data pages` in same order as Clustered Index `logical order`.

Again it is wrong. The `logical order` of data is maintained in data pages not the `physical order`. In same Data page `C` can be stored first and `A` can be stored second. Only the logical ordering is maintained in the data pages.

Comment: Prdp, you mean values inserted for Clustered Indexed Column's [ C, A ,B] physical row address wont be shifted/changed?

Comment: No the physical address will not change. According to your comment example. `C` will be stored in first physical address of data page next `A` and next `B`

Comment: In Clustered index , a single page can only have rows related to that specif c table ? Page can not contain other table rows?

Comment: @VeeraV - Yes a page will be allocated only to a table. But a single extent can have page belong to more than one table

Answer (score 0):

Check your table schema after the last `ALTER` statement and am pretty sure the clustered index on `name` is ignored `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_1 ON TEST(NAME);` since you are defining `primary key` on `N` column and defining PK on any column default creates a unique clustered index on that column and there can be utmost only one clustered index defined in a table. Thus the sorting would be on that column only. See this fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b4c8/1. As you see, commenting the primary key definition `ALTER TABLE TEST ADD  PRIMARY KEY (N);` actually sorts the table based on your clustered index column `NAME`

Comment: This is the index status :
IDX_1 clustered located on PRIMARY NAME

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK__TEST__3BD019B27F0D35A2 nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY N

Answer (score 0):

The order of rows that result from a SQL query is implementation - specific unless you use `ORDER BY`. Clustered indexes are about physical data structures. If you want a specific order as result of a query you will be able to use `ORDER BY`. Indexes help to make it fast.

Comment: So in the disk, the rows are stored based on NAME with Order By A-Z ?

Comment: This is at least my understanding of a clustered index.